# python: how does a decorator to `__init__` work?

Tags: python

Given a function

```
@mydecorator
def f(x):
    ...
f(5)
```

I could remove the decorator and call the function as

```
mydecorator(f)(5)
```

How does that translate to object methods? Especially `__init__`??

For example, I have created a decorator

```
class TestClass:
    @mydecorator
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        ...
```

that modifies arguments passed to `__init__`. I would like to *remove it*, and apply it manually only on instances I want to

- what is the appropriate syntax to do that? (eg, something like `myinstance = mydecorator(TestClass)(...)`)
- would the fact that `__new__` is called before `__init__` affect the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The decorator doesn't really modify the arguments. It's just a higher order function that returns a function given a function. You could for instance do this

```
def make_cooler_init(init):
    def new_function(*args):
        init(*args)
        print(args)
    return new_function
```

Using

```
class TestClass:
    @make_cooler_init
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

This will only change the function to print the argument after init has been called, it won't change much. To modify behavior for only some instance, you could handle that in your decorator as you can gain access to the arguments and the default function.

```
def make_cooler_init(init):
    def new_function(*args):
        if args[1] == 'True':
            init(*args)
        else:
            print(args)
    return new_function
```

Comment: My decorator *does actually* modify the arguments. The question is, if I remove it from `__init__`, how can I manually apply the same functionality when creating an object.

Comment: Can't you make a new class that inherits from the first one and call the parent one ( wrapper by the decorator function) ?

Comment: Not really, I have hundreds of such classes. But, regardless, my question is how do decorators work for object methods, as opposed to standalone functions

Comment: They work exactly the same. It creates a new function which replace the original function which is being decorated.